# Using pycparser i would like to extract the statements in a function?

Tags: python, pycparser

For example i have this statement in my function definition

```
(void)((void)( SchM_Enter_Com(COM_EXCLUSIVE_AREA_0), (*( uint8 *)((((&*bix_rx_bms_stat_ar2_BMS_BatTmp_Max_A*))))) = (uint8) ( ((*(com_UnionBuffer.raw)[(0u) + 2]* & (uint8)0xe0) >> 5u) | (((com_UnionBuffer.raw)[(0u) + 3] & (uint8)0x1f) << 3u) ), SchM_Exit_Com(COM_EXCLUSIVE_AREA_0), (uint8)(((0 < com_LMgt_RxPduGroupState[((PduIdType)0)])) ? 0u : 0x80u) ), ((Std_ReturnType)(0U)));
```

I would like to extract the name and the array indexes(which are in italics). I would really appreciate some help here?

Answer (score 0):

A good example to follow is [func_calls](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/func_calls.py) -- it extracts all calls to a given function. Similarly you can extract other parts of the AST. To explore the AST generated for your code see the [explore_ast](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/explore_ast.py) example.